# Find duplicates in SQL Server database where one of the columns must differ

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I'm trying to write a SQL query to find duplicates. What I can't manage to do is to make my query only select duplicates where one of the columns value must differ. So, I want to find all the duplicates where all the columns are the same, but one of the values must differ.

What I've got at the moment:

```
SELECT 
    a.1, underlag.1, f.1, f.2, f.3, f.4, f.5,  f.6, f.7, f.8, 
    COUNT(*) TotalCount 
FROM 
    f
JOIN
    a ON a.Id = f.Id
JOIN 
    underlag ON underlag.Id = f.Id
GROUP BY 
    a.1, underlag.1, f.1, f.2, f.3, f.4, f.5,  f.6, f.7, f.8
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY 
    underlag.1
```

The column that I want to differ is f.9 but I've no clue on how to do this. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be great!

Comment: many "find duplicate questions" asked on SO....

Comment: Yes, I know. But I can't seem to find where someone needs one of the column values to differ.

Comment: having count(distinct f.9) > 1?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
          a1 = a.[1]
        , underlag1 = underlag.[1]
        , f.[1], f.[2], f.[3], f.[4], f.[5], f.[6], f.[7], f.[8], f.[9]
        , val = SUM(1) OVER (PARTITION BY CHECKSUM(f.[1], f.[2], f.[3], f.[4], f.[5], f.[6], f.[7], f.[8]))
    FROM f
    JOIN a on a.Id = f.Id
    JOIN underlag on underlag.Id = f.Id
) t
WHERE t.val > 1
ORDER BY underlag1
```